# What are R-Ads?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, advertising

It seems like certain links from SE sites to certain other sites get implicitly converted -- or used to be -- to links of the format `http://rads.stackoverflow.com/site_name/click/token_number_thingy`.

An example is [this answer to Where to get Best resources on D language?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5208770/4532996). It links to http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321635361, which, after making SE a hundred-thousandth of a cent, redirects me to [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321635361/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321635361).

What are these, and where can I find more information about them? Are the posters making a profit by using them?